# Let $D$ be the closed unit disk embedded in $ R^2$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $D$ be the closed unit disk embedded  in $\mathbb R^2$. Identify all the boundary points of $D$ to a single point in order to form a quotient set $Q$. Endow $Q$ with the quotient topology. Prove that $Q$ is homeomorphic to the standard 2-sphere $S^2$.

I don't have any idea what to do. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: One way to do it would be to show that both are homeomorphic to the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$. You can use a diffeomorphism which maps the interior of the unit disc onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the stereographic projection of the sphere onto $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain more about the diffeomorphism?